# hide/show fields using jquery programmatically through django forms

Tags: jquery, django, html

Am trying to build a generic way of managing hiding and showing certain fields based on checkboxes. In my project, it is common that some forms might contain a check field whereby if the checkbox is ticked it will be associated with other fields and they will appear or hide based on the checkbox.

am a newbie with javascripting and am hoping someone will help me in staying in the right path here. In my django form, I used the data attribute to indicate a flag for the checkbox and data field to indicate what fields will be effected as following:

```
class PackageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    '''
    PackageForm
    '''
    class Meta:
        model = Package
        widgets = {
            'recurring_flag'      : CheckboxInput(attrs={'data-collapse-flag' : 'True'}),
            'recurring_type'      : Select(attrs={'data-collapse-id' : 'recurring_flag'}),
            'recurring_period'    : TextInput(attrs={'data-collapse-id' : 'recurring_flag'}),

        }
```

Off course, do to my limited knowledge in jquery i was able to write it statically as following

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('input[data-collapse-flag]').click(function() {
       if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
           $("label[for='id_recurring_type']").show();
           $('#id_recurring_type').show();
           $("label[for='id_recurring_period']").show();
           $('#id_recurring_period').show();
       }else{
           $('#id_recurring_type').hide();
           $("label[for='id_recurring_type']").hide();
           $('#id_recurring_period').hide();
           $("label[for='id_recurring_period']").hide();
       }
    });
```

});

but, i really want to create a single javascript file that would read the data-collapse-flag and build an action to loop through any field with data-collapge-id to apply the action too. so, I can use the script generically across all my forms wherever this scenario is required.

If anyone can advise me on how to build such a thing or point me to the method, it is very much appreciated.

regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as some conceptual support:
what you want is to loop through the descendants of a given element and based on a switch, add behavior, right?

You want to try something like:

- add classnames in appropriate places: 'collapse-stack', 'collapse-label', 'collapse-list' (label & list might even be just 'collapsable').
- have jQuery loop through these generic items.

like:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.collapse-stack').each(function(){
            //this = current collapse stack
            $(this).click(function() {
                if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
                    $(".collapse-label, .collapse-list").each(function(){
                        //this = current collapse-label
                        $(this).show();
                    });
                }else{
                    $(".collapse-label, .collapse-list").each(function(){
                        //this = current collapse-label
                        $(this).hide();
                    });
                }
            });
        })
    });
```

or somesuch. Play around with that "each" function.